# Transferring data in Java using streams

Tags: java, io, stream

I have been reading the [Java Tutorials on I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) in an attempt to understand stream and their proper usage. Say I have two devices that are connected, and an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` on both devices. How do I transfer data between the two?

For example, if I wanted to one device to send a bunch of words to the other device, which would then print them to the screen. How would that work?

```java
public class Device1 {
    // assuming connectedDevice is something
    String[] words = new String()[]{"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    OutputStream os = connectedDevice.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = connectedDevice.getInputStream();
    /*
        How to write to output stream?
    */
}

public class Device2 {
    // assuming connectedDevice is something
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    OutputStream os = connectedDevice.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = connectedDevice.getInputStream();
    /*
        How can I somehow get the words using `read()` and `put()`
        them into the ArrayList for use?
    */
}
```

Maybe I'm doing all of this wrong. Thanks in advance for any help in understanding.

Comment: Are your 2 devices running in the same JVM session?

Comment: How are the words delimited?  By spaces?  Do more than one space matter?

Comment: @assylias I imagine two completely separate devices (e.g. an Android device and a Desktop).

Comment: @Whymarrh in that case erickson's answer is one (fairly low level in the case of TCP) solution.

Comment: @GarrettHall when the words are being received, I would expect maybe separate items in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: but in a stream of bytes how will you know where one word ends and the next begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send characters, wrap your streams using an `OutputStreamWriter` on the writing side and an `InputStreamReader` on the reading side.  You can write whole strings, then read one character at a time and print it.  If you need to be really careful you should pick a fixed character encoding for both.

If you want to send whole simple objects like `String`s, you can use `DataOutputStream`/`DataInputStream`.  (For strings, use the `UTF` methods.)

If you want to get more complicated, you'll need to do serialization/deserialization of objects using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the devices are connected. For example, they might connect via TCP, or via a shared file system.

If you want to focus on streams, create an application that uses the file system. Then, use `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` to understand the stream APIs.

If your focus is on networking, you'll want to study the [networking tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html) too.